# Reroute url | Nodejs | Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

I want to redirect incoming request to different endpoints based on a query parameter in the request.

For example,

`http://localhost:9000/?category=xyz&param1=...&param2=...`

`category` value can be one of [abc, ijk, pqr, xyz].

Based on `category` value, request should get redirected to one of "/abc", "/ijk", "/pqr", "/xyz" **preserving remaining parameters.**

So, the above request should become `/xyz/?param1=...&param2=...`

I am new to Nodejs/express, I thought it is better to create different routes based on `category` value to modularize the code.

What is the ideal approach to handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Create one route for each of these values `[abc, ijk, pqr, xyz]`. For handling different query parameters (`?category=xyz`) create a middleware that transform the request url:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // adding category in the url path will redirect to the 
  // correct route after calling next function
  req.url = "/" + req.query.category;
  next();
});
```

Assuming it's a `GET` request the categories routes would be:

```
app.get('/abc', function(req, res) {
  //do stuff for 'abc' category
  res.send('abc');
});

app.get('/ijk', function(req, res) {
  //do stuff for 'ijk' category
  res.send('ijk');
});

app.get('/pqr', function(req, res) {
  //do stuff for 'pqr' category
  res.send('pqr');
});

app.get('/xyz', function(req, res) {
  //do stuff for 'xyz' category
  res.send('xyz');
});
```

Note that middleware will edit url for all requests, filter by the request url adding the path `app.use("/path", function(req,res,next)...` or add some logic inside it.

Comment: But I cannot change the pattern of incoming request url. It will always be in the format that I have specified in my question.

Comment: OK, I understand. I will edit my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the old "front page controller" pattern:

```
app.get('/', routeByParameter)
function routeByParameter(req, res){
  var category  = req.params.category
  if(category === 'abc'){
    return abcRoute(req, res)
  }
  else if(category === 'xyz'){
    return xyzRoute(req, res)
  }
}
function abcRoute(req, res){
  req.send('abc')
}
```

OR to use the "front page terminology"

```
app.get('/', dispatcher)
function dispatcher(req, res){
  var category  = req.params.category
  if(category === 'abc'){
    return viewAbc(req, res)
  }
  else if(category === 'xyz'){
    return viewXyz(req, res)
  }
}
function viewAbc(req, res){
  req.send('abc')
}
```

Alternatively, you could get in and modify or create a custom route dispatcher in the middleware...